# NameError: name 'ne_chunk' is not defined

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition

I am currently learning named-entity recognition using NLTK. Here is my code:

```
from nltk.chunk import conlltags2tree, tree2conlltags
from pprint import pprint
iob_tagged = tree2conlltags(cs)
pprint(iob_tagged)

ne_tree = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(ex)))
print(ne_tree)
```

and it's giving me an error:

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>   ----> 1 ne_tree = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(ex)))
>         2 print(ne_tree)
>
> NameError: name 'ne_chunk' is not defined

I have tried other example of NLTK, whenever it has a ne_chunk it gives an error too. Can you please help me? I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and python 3.7.1

Comment: `from nltk import ne_chunk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download the below packages:
The named entity chunker will give you a tree containing both chunks and tags.

```
 # nltk for NER-tagging
 import nltk
 from nltk.corpus import conll2000
 from nltk.chunk import conlltags2tree, tree2conlltags
 from nltk.chunk import ne_chunk
 from nltk import pos_tag

 sentence = "Clement and Mathieu are working at Apple."
 ne_tree = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Its work for me thanks @thrinadh

```
    import nltk
    from nltk.corpus import conll2000
    from nltk.chunk import conlltags2tree, tree2conlltags
    from nltk.chunk import ne_chunk
    from nltk import pos_tag

    sentence = "Clement and Mathieu are working at Apple."
    ne_tree = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)))
```